# With Azure AD, How can I send a change password request with a temporary password?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a specific question when it comes to azure AD and graph API.

I'm making a simple change password request to the API. This works for when the user is able to sign in. However, if the user had their password reset to a temporary password via the portal, then the next time they log in they are required to change their password. The problem I have with this is when trying to get the authentication token for that user an exception is returned:

```
AADSTS50055: Force Change Password.
```

So if I can't get an authentication token, how am I supposed to send the change password request using Graph API so that my user can change their password within my app?

Below is my code for changing a password to a user who can already log in:

```
public SendPasswordChangeRequest(string userId, string newPass, string oldPass) {
    try {
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        string action = string.Format("/users/{0}/changePassword", user.DistinguishedName);
        string url = string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}{1}?api-version=1.6", tenantId, action);
        object bodyObject = new { currentPassword = oldPass, newPassword = newPass }; 
        string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObject);

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantName));
        UserPasswordCredential credential = new UserPasswordCredential(userId, oldPass); //userId and oldPass are parameters passed in

        AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net/", clientId, credential).Result;
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = http.SendAsync(request).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //authResult throws the error into here
        //Error returned from Azure AD:
        //AADSTS50055: Force Change Password.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't.

This is a good example of why use of the username/password flow is discouraged in any situation in which you can be using any of the interactive authentication flows. From the [OAuth 2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3), which is what this pattern is invoking (emphasis added):

> The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password) can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access token.  The credentials should only be used when there is a high degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged application), **and when other authorization grant types are not available (such as an authorization code)**.

If your application is a native client application (i.e. a rich client application), you should invoke one of the `AcquireToken` flows that pops up a sign-in prompt with the Azure AD-hosted sign-in page. This will provide the user the opportunity to change their password (and allows other interrupts, such as multi-factor authentication).

For other scenarios (web app, single-page app, etc.), [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) has additional details, and samples and additional reference can be found in the [Azure Active Directory developer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide).

Comment: Thanks for your response! That is what I feared. Hopefully this answer helps anyone else asking the same question.